# SQL: Populate a date-column with random test data - how do I make a subquery run for each record in a table?

Tags: oracle, random, plsql

So I've got an oracle 11g SQL db. It has a table which contains a date-field. I just added the field, so it currently contains no data.

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ some_id ║ some_date ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1       ║ null      ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2       ║ null      ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 3       ║ null      ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

I wrote a quick query to generate some test-data in our testing environment:

```
update some_table 
set some_date =(SELECT TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J') FROM DUAL)
where some_id = any(select some_other_id from vw_some_complicated_view);
```

Now this sub-query, probably not so elegantly, generates a random date in a range:

```
SELECT TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J') FROM DUAL
```

So I want this subquery to run for each record in the table... in other words I want to set every date to be a random date - but not the *same* random date.

What I got:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ some_id ║ some_date ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1       ║ 08-DEC-15 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2       ║ 08-DEC-15 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 3       ║ 08-DEC-15 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

What I want:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ some_id ║ some_date ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1       ║ 04-JAN-16 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2       ║ 20-DEC-15 ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║ 3       ║ 03-MAR-16 ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

How can I accomplish this, preferably in a normal SQL query format. I looked at other answers where they generate (non-date) random data, and they just use this format without issues.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use update statement for each row where some_date is null  set some_date = TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J');

OFC firstly set all date fields to null.

Comment: add tag oracle, the question relates to oracle

Comment: @z48o0 I don't understand how that's different from what I'm doing now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a scalar sub-query is used, that statement is parsed once used for each row in the update. But if the sub query changes over for each row of the main query, that scalar sub-query is parsed and executed for each row and the new value is used for that row.

**Original Scenario**

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE test_skg1(some_id NUMBER, some_date DATE)
  2  /

Table created

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO test_skg1 VALUES (1, NULL);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO test_skg1 VALUES (2, NULL);

1 row inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO test_skg1 VALUES (3, NULL);

1 row inserted

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_skg1;

   SOME_ID SOME_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 
         2 
         3 

SQL> 
SQL> UPDATE test_skg1
  2    SET some_date = (SELECT TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J') FROM DUAL)
  3  /

3 rows updated

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_skg1;

   SOME_ID SOME_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 3/1/2016
         2 3/1/2016
         3 3/1/2016

SQL> ROLLBACK;

Rollback complete
```

**Update**: Scalar sub query changing for each row of the main query, I have added `some_id` from the main query so that for each row, there is different scalar sub query.

```
SQL> UPDATE test_skg1 a
  2  SET a.some_date = (SELECT TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01' + a.some_id,'J'))),'J') FROM DUAL);

3 rows updated
SQL> SELECT * FROM test_skg1;

   SOME_ID SOME_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 12/28/2015
         2 6/24/2016
         3 2/17/2016
SQL> ROLLBACK;

Rollback complete
```

Now I am calling the function directly, without using sub query..

```
SQL> UPDATE test_skg1
  2    SET some_date = TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J')
  3  /

3 rows updated

SQL> SELECT * FROM test_skg1;

   SOME_ID SOME_DATE
---------- -----------
         1 7/15/2016
         2 4/15/2016
         3 6/11/2016

SQL>
```

Each time a new value is generated as there is no dependency of scalar sub-query.

Comment: So this is caused by cashing function results, not by how frequently the sub-query is run...  and I basically had to remove "Select" and "FROM DUAL" to stop caching. 
Thanks!

Comment: It is incorrect to say that a subquery's result is "cached" and that it "ages out". These are **scalar subqueries** - their result is used for each row in the target rowset regardless.

Comment: *"scalar sub-query is parsed and executed for each row"* no, it isn't - scalar sub-queries are evaluated once and the value used for each row.

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this below code. It may help you to generate the random date.

--Creation of dummy table
CREATE TABLE RANDOM_TEST
  ( num NUMBER, DATE_COL DATE
  );


--IOnsertion of  dummy data
INSERT INTO RANDOM_TEST
SELECT LEVEL,NULL FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10;


-- Updating values with some random data
MERGE INTO RANDOM_TEST rt USING
(SELECT NUM FROM RANDOM_TEST
)A ON (rt.num = a.num)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET DATE_COL = SYSDATE+A.num;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: can you check if merge statement is working for you..i suspect.

Answer (score 0):

for insert you can use

```
insert into test_table
SELECT level,TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J') FROM DUAL
connect by level<100;
```

for update you can try this...

```
 UPDATE vish_test a
  SET a.idate = (SELECT TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J') FROM DUAL)
 where rank_id in(select rank_id from vish_test);
```

Comment: please map some_id with rank_id and some_date with idate.

Answer (score -3):

You an use Plsql Program with cursor and update rows with where condition 
Like below
just add cursor and try once

```
declare
begin 
update Table_name set 
some_date=(SELECT TO_DATE( TRUNC( DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(TO_CHAR(DATE '2015-12-01','J'),
TO_CHAR(DATE '2016-08-01','J'))),'J') FROM DUAL) where some_id=1;
end;
```

Comment: So just add 'declare begin' to the start and 'end;' to the end? I get the same result - every date in the date column is the same.